# How to digitize from a map with additional detail views?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I have a map with a river that includes islands within it.  Some islands have a blown up version (detail views) outside of the river showing land ownership details.

I would like to make polygons (shapefiles) of the large islands on the outside of the river and then copy these polygons and shrink them to fit within the lines of their matching islands within the river and then safe the result.  I suspect that the copy and paste part is possible but can the "shrink or resize" part be done?

I want this so that I can do distance queries along the river.  Is this possible and how would I do it?  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think a good approach would be to georeference the "blown up" version of the maps correctly. Then you can digitize the features in the correct location and with the correct size.

Comment: It will be more accurate to do it this way.